# Parse and evaluate quosures from string

Tags: r, rlang, quosure

Is there a way to parse and evaluate a quosure from a string. I would like to achieve the same output as in the example below:

```
library(rlang)
a <- 10
quo(UQ(a) + 2 * b)
## <quosure: global>
## ~10 + 2 * b
```

but starting from

```
t <- "UQ(a) + 2 * b"
```

What I tried so fare is:

```
# Trial 1:
quo(expr(t))

# Trial 2: 
parse_quosure(t)

# Trial 3:
quo(parse_quosure(t))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this may be a job for `expr_interp`.  According to the documentation it "manually processes unquoting operators in expressions...".

So you can first use `parse_quosure` and then process the unquoting operators via `expr_interp`.

```
expr_interp(parse_quosure(t))

<quosure: global>
~10 + 2 * b
```

Comment: It seems that `rlang::parse_quosure` has been superceeded by `rlang::parse_quo` and now requires an `env=` argument to be supplied. See https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rlang/html/parse_expr.html

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `parse` to convert `t` to expression and `eval` to evaluate it.

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("quo(",t,")")))
#<quosure: global>
#~10 + 2 * b
```